Counting lattice points inside a parallelepiped
The problem I am about to state is in three dimensions and does not follow from Davenport's theorem. Its two-dimensional version is an immediate consequence of Pick's theorem.
Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$. I will now define some properties of a parallelepiped $P$, for which we want to count the lattice points in the interior.
Let $M, B>0$ be two real numbers, where $M>>B$. Think of $M$ as a large number and $B$ as a constant.

Base: the base of the parallelepiped $P$ will be a square $S$ of side-length $M$ (when I say square, I mean the boundary along with the interior). The square $S$ can be placed arbitrarily in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The only constraint is that S does not contain any points of $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Finally, let $u$ be a unit vector normal to $S$.
Small slant-vector: let $v\in \mathbb{Z}^3$ be a lattice-vector with norm $\|v\|_2\le B$. Suppose that the inner product $v\cdot u \ge 0$.

The parallelepiped is defined as $P:=\{x+tv\ :\ x\in S, \ t\in[0,1]\}$.
Note that $vol(P)=M^2 (v\cdot u)$. The goal is to prove (or disprove) that
$$\left | \frac{|\mathbb{Z}^3 \cap P|}{M^2} - v \cdot u \right| \to 0 $$
as the real number $M\to \infty$. In other words, $vol(P)$ is a "first-order" approximation for $|\mathbb{Z}^3 \cap P|$.
Comments:

Observe that if we drop the assumption that $S$ does not contain any lattice point or the assumption that $v\in \mathbb{Z}^3$, then the statement does not hold.
Motivation: This problem comes from the theory of elasticity in physics. It is a folklore result in this field that the macroscopic continuous equations can be derived as a limit of a simple atomic model. However, I could not find a rigorous proof, so I want to prove it. The above (hopefully true) fact is needed for the proof.


Presumably you have heard of "Ehrhart theory" before. Not saying it directly answers your question, because it normally restricts to rational polytopes and you are looking at parallelepipeds with arbitrary real vertices, but I think people have considered generalizations of Ehrhart theory including "real Ehrhart theory."

What is the difference between being a difference of two lattice points, and being a lattice point?

@GerryMyerson you are right. I edited my question.

@SamHopkins Hugh Thomas below gave an elementary proof. In any case, thanks for your answer!!

I have not filled in absolutely all the details, but hopefully this is enough to be convincing.
Let's let $M$ take positive integer values, and let's consider the parallelepiped: $$P'=\{x+Mtv\mid x\in S, t\in [0,1]\}.$$ Because $v$ is a lattice vector and $S$ contains no lattice points, the number of lattice points in $P'$ is $M$ times the number of lattice points in $P$.
The volume of $P'$ is $M^3 (u\cdot v)$. For each lattice point $x$ in $P'$, consider a unit cube centred at $x$. "Most" of the lattice points in $P'$ are going to have the property that their entire cube lies in $P'$. More precisely, the difference between the volume of $P'$ and the sum of the volumes of the cubes centred at lattice points inside $P'$ is going to be bounded by something proportional to the area of the sides of $P'$ (because only lattice points near one of the boundary walls won't simply have their whole cube contained in $P'$). This area is of course quadratic in $M$. Another way to say this is that that the union of the unit cubes centred at the lattice points of $P'$ is a reasonable approximation to $P'$, with the difference in the two volumes being bounded by something quadratic in $M$.
Thus, the volume of $P'$ and the sum of the volumes of the cubes around the lattice points in $P'$ differ by an amount bounded by $cM^2$ for some $c$ depending on $S$ and $v$. The sum of the volumes of the unit cubes is, of course, the number of lattice points in $P'$.
Thus, $|M^3 (u\cdot v) - M|P\cap \mathbb Z^3|| < cM^2$. Dividing through by $M^3$, we get the desired result.

I think this correct! The idea is that if the length of v is linear in M, then the problem is easy. In our case, because v is a lattice vector, you can reduce it to the previous case. Neat! Thank you, I am grateful!!
